# SQLITE: pull items in the same order as IN array

Tags: sqlite

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * from tWords where WordAton IN ("bbb", "aaa2", "ccc", "aaa1")
```

the query returns first the results for "aaa1" then for "aaa2" then for "bbb" and then for "ccc". Is there a way to return the results in the order of the input array, which means first the results for "bbb" then for "aaa2"... etc.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply conditional ordering like this:

```
SELECT * 
from tWords 
where WordAton IN ('bbb', 'aaa2', 'ccc', 'aaa1')
order by case WordAton
  when 'bbb' then 1
  when 'aaa2' then 2
  when 'ccc' then 3
  when 'aaa1' then 4
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL (not just SQLite), the only way to *always* return rows in a given order is with a SQL `ORDER BY ...` clause. So the short answer is, "No", there's no *simple* way to return rows in the order given by the contents of an `IN (...)` clause.

You *could* use a common table expression (CTE) to define a sort order, but that's usually not worth the trouble. This isn't the same thing as ordering by the contents of a `IN (...)` clause, but it *looks* the same. (You're ordering by the sort order specified in the CTE.)

```
with ordered_words as (
  select 1 as sort_order, 'bbb' as WordAton union
  select 2,               'aaa2' union
  select 3,               'ccc' union
  select 4,               'aaa1'
)
select t.WordAton
from tWords t
join ordered_words o on t.WordAton = o.WordAton
where t.WordAton in ('bbb', 'aaa2', 'ccc', 'aaa1')
order by o.sort_order;
```